# Error when trying to deploy Windows XP SP3 with WDS

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-xp, deployment, wds, mdt-2010

I have created a WDS server running Windows Server 2008 R2. I have built my custom images of Windows 7 using WAIK and MDT 2010 that are installed on the server. I used this [guide](http://blogs.technet.com/b/danstolts/archive/2010/03/11/deploy-windows-7-the-easy-way-using-wds-mdt-and-aik-step-by-step-video.aspx) to help me through the process. The Windows 7 images that I have created capture and deploy properly.

I am attempting to follow the same steps from the guide I linked to capture and deploy a Windows XP SP3 image. I am able to sysprep and capture the reference machine with no errors. I am then able to import the custom `.wim` that I just captured in to MDT 2010 with no issues either. However when I try to deploy this image to a test virtual machine I get the following error:

**Deployment Error:**
[image]

I have made sure that the `.iso` that I am importing the source files from originally to create the sysprep and capture sequence is indeed a Windows XP SP3 iso.

When I first select a PE boot environment before I deploy I select the x86 PE boot image that I created originally when making this for my Windows 7 deployments. Could this be the issue? If so how do I make a boot image specific for Windows XP SP3 deployments?

I have Googled around for this error and some places point to the deployment image not being able to find `setup.exe` and other important system files for installing the operating system. If so, how do I add these to the image?

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked the log files? press F8 when that error screen is up to open a command window. Navigate to x:\minint\smsosd\osdlogs or X:\Windows\temp\BDDLogs (also possibly c:\minint\smsosd\osdlogs) and find the bdd.log and smsts.log files. They should show specific information to help with this error. More information on MDT log files can be found [in this blog post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askcore/archive/2012/05/08/mdt-2010-amp-2012-my-deployment-failed-what-and-where-are-logs-i-should-review.aspx)

Comment: @WinOutreach4 Well I feel pretty dumb. I followed your link and found the appropriate log file that contained my error. It appears that I did not create my test virtual machine with enough disk space. Guess that is what I get for accepting the defaults blindly. If you make this an answer I will accept.

Comment: Fantastic! Glad you have it worked out. Added as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the log files? Press F8 when that error screen is up to open a command window. Navigate to x:\minint\smsosd\osdlogs or X:\Windows\temp\BDDLogs (also possibly c:\minint\smsosd\osdlogs) and find the bdd.log and smsts.log files. They should show specific information to help with this error. More information on MDT log files can be found [in this blog post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askcore/archive/2012/05/08/mdt-2010-amp-2012-my-deployment-failed-what-and-where-are-logs-i-should-review.aspx)